# TypeError: Cannot read property 'listOrderJson' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

Im trying to link a route to a controller vs doing the code within the route definiton.  Here is my controller:

```
const {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose');
const {Order} = require('../models/order');

module.exports.listAllJson = function(req, res) {
    res.send({"Here": "something"});
}
```

And here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Order} = require('./models/order');
var {orderController} = require('./controllers/orderController');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/orders', (req, res) => {
    orderController.listAllJson().bind(orderController);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Started on port 3000');
});

module.exports = {app};
```

When I hit my /orders route using postman I get:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'listOrderJson' of undefined error.

I added the 'bind' part to the function call after searching here on stack overflow a ton, but it didn't help.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

orderController is `{ listAllJson: fn }` so you can simply destructure and use it.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Order} = require('./models/order');
var {listAllJson} = require('./controllers/orderController');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/orders',  listAllJson);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Started on port 3000');
});

module.exports = {app};
```

Also minor note use `res.json({"Here": "something"});` it does the stringifying and set the headers.

Comment: Thank you!  Totally worked.  So as I add more functions to my controller would I just add them with listAllJson comma separated?

Comment: Yes you can do `var {listAllJson, listAllCsv} = require(...);` which is a good pattern since it lets you decouple your handlers from your routing.